# Wrong format of screenshots for Apple's app store

Tags: png, screenshot

I want to publish an app to Apple's app store. For this purpose I have to upload some screenshots.
I created three screenshots with the resolutions 1242 x 2208 (iphone) and 2048 x 2732 (ipad). So I have now 6 pictures in png format.
But if I upload one these files I get the error message that the screenshots have the wrong format. What do I wrong?

Comment: did you capture these images with the simulator or some kind of screen capture on your puter ?   iOS simulator will dish-out the appropriate sizes. Goto Simulator->File->Save Screen Shot

Comment: No, I used the physical devices (iPhone 8 Plus) and iPad Pro to capture the screnshots.

Comment: The use of the term "format" instead of "size" suggests that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878917/2564301) may apply.

Comment: I had a similar error to you. I had tried loading several images at once, past the 10 image limit. The images were correct (they were made in the simulator, and later loaded individually without a problem).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you upload it in **`png`** format.

Answer (score 0):

I screenshot the image via the iOS simulator and not able to upload. Tried to open the file in Adobe Photoshop and it says "Not a PNG file". But the file was saved as .png by iOS simulator.

What I did was to change the extension to .jpg without doing anything, and now able to upload to App Store Connect screenshot.