# Why is there an option for two 12.9" size screenshots in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store-connect

[image: App Store Connect]

In App Store Connect there is the option to provide screenshots for the 12.9" iPad Pro (2nd Gen) and the 12.9" iPad Pro (3rd Gen).

This doesn't make sense to me as the display size and the resolution (2048 x 2732) is the same for both devices.

Why would you bother adding the 2nd lot of screenshots and why is this an option?

Comment: Probably to allow for apps that include the device bezel in their screen shots to provide different imagery to iPad Pro 3rd generation owners.

Comment: It's the only explanation i could think of but it still seems strange.

Comment: I have a question on that front as well. If i have an iPad Application, why would I require to provide screenshots of iPhoneXS and iPhone8Plus as well?

Comment: but what about if my app runs on iPad 3rd gen but does not have anything specific for that device? The screenshots would look the same and I'm not using device frames. So why should I provide a different lot?

Comment: @Ele - exactly! Nevertheless you have to provide both.

Comment: It's no longer an option. Both 2nd and 3rd Gen screenshots are now each required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you take screenshots for the iPad, in the screenshots for the iPad Pro 2nd generation the device should be with the home button, and for the iPad Pro 3rd generation - without the button.

Comment: In the absence of a better explanation, I'm going to accept this.

Comment: This is beyond moronic, and therefore as expected from Apple. Glad someone else asked this question and not me.

Answer (score 20):

As previously mentioned, if you are adding device frames to your screenshots, the frames must be different. The 2nd gen has a home button, the 3rd gen does not.

Additionally, the actual screenshot from the 3rd gen has the gesture bar covering your app, the 2nd gen will not. I would expect Apple to refuse screenshots claiming to be third gen without the gesture bar, unless that's how it appears in your app.

[image: Bottom of iPad Pro 12.9 3rd gen showing gesture bar]