# IOS Screenshot properties. (The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong. Learn More.)

Tags: ios, app-store, screenshot

I am unable to place screenshots in the app previews and screenshots box. I have tried resizing the photos to the specs listed on the Screenshot specification page (https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devd274dd925) .
 I am unable to use the simulator as the app I work on requires bluetooth to connect. I am not sure what I am doing wrong? My photos are .png . I am changing the size in Preview on my mac. 
I feel like I am missing something obvious. 
Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some sort of flag in your application to bypass features that requires bluetooth connection if device is a simulator. Check this answer to query if device is a simulator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24869607/6940228. Check this answer to solve screenshot issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173632/6940228

Comment: Thanks for the response Bhaumik.