# Widescreen detection iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I have an issue using this code bellow:

```
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

In iOS 8 it's not working any more. Always returns NO; Some suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit!**
My app is in Landscape

```
NSLog(@"%f",[[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height);
```

iOS 7
printed : 568.00000

iOS 8
printed : 320.00000

Comment: Why do you need to detect it?

Comment: Adjustment the graphic.

Comment: Check this post below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices?rq=1