# How can I change constraints for different screen sizes programmatically?

Tags: swift, constraints, size-classes

Hello I've just started programming and I'm trying to write with code instead of using the storyboard, but the constraints I added do not work at different screen sizes How do I solve this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS different constraints for different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651057/ios-different-constraints-for-different-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Since you do it in the code, you can check the size class before adding any constraint like this:

```
if (self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact) {
    /* add needed constraints */
}
```

Also you can implement the `traitCollectionDidChange:` method to automatically be called when a trait changes due to autorotation.