# How to compute the correct image Sizes for different iOS Displays?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a logo image which should be displayed at 95 x 95 pt at iPhone6. This means the logo image has size 190 x 190 px since iPhone6 scales at 2x.

**What is the correct size in px for this image on iPhone6Plus to have the same size?**

iPhone6Plus scales at 3x this would lead to **285 x 285 px**.
But, you can also computed it differently too.

Screen size in px:

- iPhone6: 750 x 1334 px
- iPhone6Plus: 1242 x 2208 px

Now you can compute:

```
190 / 750 = x / 1242
```

and solve this for x. This leads to **314 x 314 px**.

So I get two different values for the correct image size on iPhone6Plus. 
**285 x 285 px** and **314 x 314 px**.

**Which one is correct?**

Comment: General rule of thumb, for iphone devices with retina display make your images 2x for iphone6P its 3x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices/26017764#26017764

Comment: What do you mean by "the same size" on iPhone 6 Plus.  Will it be the same size in inches as the iPhone 6, or will it take up the same percentage of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode you can now use vector pdf images. It will then scale them automatically when building. Support for this has become better in Xcode 7.
This will automatically generate all the sizes you need, this essentially future proofs your image assets.

[a guide to vector assets](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/)

[a link to all the awesomeness that assets can do now](http://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know)

Comment: Wow! I did't know what is possible with those assets. Great article.

Comment: This vector feature does not work for me in Xcode 7 as only @1x images are created. Maybe this is because these pictures are used to generate texture for SpriteKit. I'll create a question about this but currently I have to give further investigations.

Answer (score 0):

The scaling on the 6+ is a little bit tricky.

You need to multiply the @2x size by 1.5.

Here is an example:

You got an image of 100x100px.

You need an image of 150x150px to be displayed on your iPhone 6+ in clear definition. (@3x)

Here is a useful link:
[Icon & imagesizes on iOS devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)