# How to switch to different Storyboard for iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uistoryboard, iphone-5

Just as an app utilizes different storyboards for iPad and iPhone, I would like my app to use a different storyboard for the iPhone 5.  Since there is no option in the Info.plist to select default storyboard for iPhone 5, how would I programmatically call the storyboard?

I do not want to use AutoLayout for this app unless it is absolutely the last resort.  I understand how to detect if a user is using an iPhone 5 or other device with the same screen size. I just need to know how to set the default storyboard without the plist.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I was looking for the same answer couple of weeks ago here's my solution hope helps..

```
-(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch


    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
    {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

        // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
        UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone35" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
    {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

        // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
        UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone4" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

    {   // The iOS device = iPad

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    }
}
```

Call this method under AppDelegate ddiFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method 
And also don't forget the name your storyboards properly

Hope helps...

Comment: Thank you! I've spent way too much time looking for this exact answer.  Problem sovled!

Comment: The method compiles fine, but it does not seem to actually do anything on my end.  Any ideas?

Comment: This code works fine! Thanks @lionserdar. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thank u so much dear. Very much helpful to me. Thanks once again

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me - slight refinement with wrapping getting the storyboard in a function

```
-(UIStoryboard*) getStoryboard {   
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = nil;
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {         
        storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }else{
        if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
            // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch
            CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480){
                // iPhone 3/4x
                storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone_4" bundle:nil];

            }else if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568){
                // iPhone 5 etc
                storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone_5" bundle:nil];
            }
        }
    }

    ASSERT(storyBoard);
    return storyBoard;
}

UIStoryboard* mainStoryBoard = [self getStoryboard];
    self.initialViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: why the ASSERT(storyboard) ?

Comment: just a sanity check that the storyboard exists.  ASSERT macro should be a no op in release build

Comment: aha... I've never really used it, so wasn't sure. i get the context now... any recommended tutorials on using them ?