# Loading a different storyboard depending if the conditions are met

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Like setting up a code so that detects the iPhone's resolution and loads a certain viewcontroller depending on it's resolution.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // load ViewContollerA 
} else {
    // load ViewContollerB
}
```

How to set code to load a storyboard? Thanks.

I'm thinking it's probably going to have to be connected to an IBAction so that when you press on the button it verifies what the resolution is and loads the next storyboard (either A or B) depending on that.

Comment: You may find some hints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066525/prevent-segue-in-prepareforsegue-method), it's about preventing a segue but may just as well be used for choosing one.

Answer (score 0):

I answered that question couple of days back. Here

[How to switch to different Storyboard for iPhone 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696242/how-to-switch-to-different-storyboard-for-iphone-5/12696370#12696370)

Hope helps...