# 4 Storyboards for IPhone4-IPhone5 and IPad-IPadMini?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch to different Storyboard for iPhone 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696242/how-to-switch-to-different-storyboard-for-iphone-5)

Dealing with dimensions on XCode is a nightmare, I was wondering if I can create one storyboard for different IPhone/IPad devices instead of trying to figure out in the code

Comment: If you think having these 4 screen sizes is bad, try programming for Android.

Comment: :) it must be painful...

Comment: What are the four? There are three. 3.5" iPhone/iPod touch, 4" iPhone/iPod touch, and iPad.

Comment: iPad mini is the same as the iPad

Comment: You mean, iPad and iPad mini have same dimmension?

Comment: Even if the app fits the same in iPad and ipAd mini, I would like to have the option to distinguish them in order to, for example, make the font and buttons bigger than iPad to make it clear to read and touch in a smaller device