# Create separate storyboards for iphone 4 and 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to create 2 storyboards, one for iPhone 4 and one for iPhone 5. I want it to be detected at launch which device the user is using. I've used the following code and implemented it in my app delegate.m, but receive the error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier "initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize"
```

Here's the code I've used:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


-(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch


        CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
        {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
            UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone35" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

            // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

            // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
            self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

            // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }

        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
        {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

            // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
            UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone4" bundle:nil];

            // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
            UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

            // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

            // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
            self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

            // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        }

    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

    {   // The iOS device = iPad

        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    }
```

Is there maybe something I need to import to fix the error?

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696242/how-to-switch-to-different-storyboard-for-iphone-5 and call your method inside **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**.

Comment: That's what I've done above, right?

Comment: I think you need to call method in **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** as given the answer below by Martin.

Comment: When I do and I launch the app on the iphone 5 device the app is only showing my first storyboard not the one that is supposed to launch when you use iPhone 5

Comment: Put Breakpoint and check in which condition its going. You will know which line causes the problem and make sure you put the correct name from iPhone4 & 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to *define* a method inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    -(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {
        // ... your code ...
    }
    return YES;
}
```

This is not what you want and btw. nested functions (or methods) are not supported
in Objective-C.

What you probably meant is to define a method and *call* it 
inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`:

```
-(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {
    // ... your code ...
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When I do this and launch the app, it's not loading the iPhone 5 supported storyboard. It's loading my main storyboard instead.

Comment: @user2667306: I would suggest to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint in `initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize` and single-step through your code. What value has iOSDeviceScreenSize? Which if-block is executed? And so on ...

Comment: It works! but I've added a new storyboard and I can't add any actions to the new storyboard, why?

Comment: @user2667306: I would suggest that you post a new question if new problems arise that you cannot solve yourself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it could just be an error here, but you're entering an action void in didFinishApplicationLaunchingWithOptions?

did you try to fit everything in didFinishApplicationLaunchingWithOptions without simply use this action void?