# Submitting iOS App with two different targets

Tags: ios, app-store, store, submission

I'm developing an iOS app with two different targets. The first target is deployed to support iOS 5 and iOS 6, and the second target for iOS 7. Both targets have different user interfaces (different storyboards), but they have the same code. I have been searching the way to submit both targets for the same app, but I didn't find the answer. Does someone know how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Choose the storyboard at runtime based on the availability of features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't submit the same app twice for different iOS versions.

Since all apps submitted must support iOS 7 and be built with the iOS 7 SDK you will need to create one app. Thus you can not submit an iOS 5/6 only app.

You will need to create an app that support both iOS 5,6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @rckoenes :

> Both targets have different user interfaces (different storyboards)

For this, [you need to switch storybaords accordingly, while the app about to gets launch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696242/how-to-switch-to-different-storyboard-for-iphone-5)

Comment: Thanks, now I'm selecting the storyboard at runtime and it works with one target.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit an app with a different bundle id.

You can have two info.plist in your xcodeproject, and link only one to each target

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit one ipa build with different targets having different version of deployment target in one app.

So in your case you have to load different storyboard based on iOS version.

You can find iOS version using below code and load respective storyboard in your app.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```