# How to make view size adaptive for ip 3.5, 4,4 retina

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I am struggling with IB to make my views and controllers adaptive for all phone types. What I am experiencing is that 3.5 size works fine but when I run on the 4 simulator and 4 device there'll be black bars above and below the views.
How can I make the view adaptive to the device size? Code or IB option? I played with the `Size:Freeform` / `3.5 Full screen` and `4 Retina full screen` option but neither makes a difference. All subviews of my UINavigaionViewController have Size:inferred enabled.

Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to tell the OS that you are iPhone 5 ready.

You do that by adding a `Default-568h@2x.png` default screen.
That's all there is to it.

See an exhaustive list of steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824358/about-supporting-iphone-5-when-using-nib-files-and-backwards-compatibility).

Comment: ha, such a sophisticated system relies on the size of an image. that's kind of paradox.

Comment: Check √ then (-: The same team who wrote the icn# series on Macintosh System 7 I suppose. But this conversation shall be taken offline.